# Remove column from Pandas multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as:

```
                                                   Year  Value
Country     Element    Item               ItemCode           
Afghanistan Production Wheat and products 2511     1961  2279
                                                   1962  2279
                                                   1963  1947
                                                   1964  2230
                                                   1965  2282
```

I would like to remove the level `ItemCode` from the multiindex, yielding:

```
                                          ItemCode Year  Value
Country     Element    Item                          
Afghanistan Production Wheat and products 2511     1961  2279
                                          2511     1962  2279
                                          2511     1963  1947
                                          2511     1964  2230
                                          2511     1965  2282
```

I know that it is possible with brute force, but I was wondering if there is any `pandas` specific command to this via a shortcut?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

`df.reset_index(level='ItemCode')`

Comment: I knew there was a shortcut! Thanks :)